# ObjectDisposedException while actually no connection is needed

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm getting the following error:

> System.ObjectDisposedException: The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection.

It's really funny as

1.I use eager loading

2-Tracing shows the loaded values

3-Getting data works in first lines of code and then in later lines gives the error

**Model**:

```
public class EndedAuctionsModel{
    public Auction[] Auctions { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
    public int PerPage = 10;
    public int Page { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller**:

```
    public ActionResult Ended(EndedAuctionsModel m)
    {
        m.Page = ((string)ControllerContext.RouteData.Values["id"]).PInt(1);
        using(Entities db = new Entities())
        {
            m.Auctions = db.Auctions.Include("participations").Where(a => a.Ends < DateTime.Now).OrderByDescending(a=>a.Ends).Skip((m.Page-1)*m.PerPage).Take(m.PerPage).ToArray();
            m.Count = db.Auctions.Count(a => a.Ends < DateTime.Now);
        }
        return View(m);
    }
```

**View**:

```
        <div class="participated">
            @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Auctions.Length; i++)
            {
                Participation last = Model.Auctions[i].Participations.OrderBy(p => p.Date).Last();
                <div class="col-md-12 auction" style="background:#eee; margin:5px 0;padding:10px;" data-id="@Model.Auctions[i].Id">
                    <div class="col-md-4"><img src="~/data/pimgs/@Model.Auctions[i].AuctionImages.First().Filename" style="width:100%;border-radius:10px;" /></div>
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <h3>@Model.Auctions[i].Name</h3>
                        <div><i class="fa fa-money big-blue"></i>قیمت شروع مزایده: <strong>@Model.Auctions[i].BasePrice.Value.ToString("N0")</strong></div>
                        @{ string username = last.GetUserName(); if (username == null) { username = "-"; } }
                        <div><i class="fa fa-gavel big-blue"></i>برنده مزائده: <strong class="last-user"><a href="/Home/Profiles/@username">@username</a></strong></div>
                        <div><i class="fa fa-user big-blue"></i>قیمت نهایی: <strong class="last-price">@((Model.Auctions[i].BasePrice + Model.Auctions[i].Participations.Count * Model.Auctions[i].StepPrice).Value.ToString("N0"))</strong></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                            }
        </div>
```

The error is on the 5th line of the view `data-id="@Model.Auctions[i].Id"`

[image]

Comment: Is `AuctionImages` being loaded initially? (`@Model.Auctions[i].AuctionImages.First().Filename`)

Comment: @StephenMuecke thanks a lot. it solved the problem, but the reason I couldn't find the problem was that the error is raised somewhere before that line. & why is that?

Comment: Razor does that sometimes. Best to put a breakpoint on the view and step through it to fine the line throwing the exception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your view includes (in the `<img>` tag)

```
@Model.Auctions[i].AuctionImages.First().Filename
```

but your not including `AuctionImages` in your query. Change it to

```
m.Auctions = db.Auctions.Include("participations").Include("AuctionImages").Where(....
```

Comment: Can you help me with this question please or guide me please:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41118619/displaying-database-and-table-creation-result-at-the-end