# Displaying database and table creation result at the end

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, linq, ado.net

I am creating database and tables from c# code so at the end i would like to display result like below:

```
TableName          Result
Table1             Success
Table2             Success
Table3             Error:Inapproproiate datatype precision for decimal


public class Tables
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public List<Column> Columns { get; set; }
}

public class Column
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Datatype { get; set; }
    public string IsNullable { get; set; }
    public Int32? Size { get; set; }
    public byte? NumericPrecision { get; set; }
    public Int32? NumericScale { get; set; }
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CreateDatabase(string database,List<Tables> tables)
{
   //Here i am thinking to call just method of repository that will create whole database structure for me..
}

public class DatabaseRepo
{
    public void CreateDb(string database,List<Tables> tables)
    {
        var queryList = new List<string>();
        queryList.Add("CREATE DATABASE " + database);

        foreach (var table in tables)
        {
             queryList.Add(CreateTableScript(table.Name, table.Columns)); //This method will create table script for me.
        }
    }
}
```

**Note**:I am just considering Datatype,Isnullable,Precision and scale value for insert operation

Now my question is should i execute individual table or i should execute list of all tables at once and most important thing is how do i process this tables by opening a connection 1 time and closing connection  after all database and tables are created and display result for each table at the end???

I am thinking of class like below which will return result to my web service:

```
Public class Result
{
   public string TableName { get; set; }
   public bool Status { get; set; }
   public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
}
```

Can anybody please guide me to do this??

Comment: I wouldn't reinvent the wheel. There is already a Net object DataTable.  Why not use it.  There is also a DataSet that can contain multiple DataTables.  And you can use a DataAdapter which will automatically fill the datatables.  See msdn : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter(v=vs.110).aspx.  The easiest was of display a DataTable is to use a DataGridView like dgv1.DataSource = dt;

Comment: you'll need to think about a meaningful error handling here. You can attempt to create table by table, in a loop, and continue on error, and finally output the list of failed CREATE TABLE statements at once. Same connection can be reused for all statements. Entity Framework has already solved all of this ("migrations"), maybe that would be an option for you? your current model is missing primary key information.

Comment: @jdweng :I cannot return datatable to webservice so i have to return output in the form of class that is why i a not using datatable

Comment: What is the difference between sending classes to webservice and sending datatable to webservice?  They should be the same.  Maybe you want to serialize to jason?